# SVN infinite loop of failures (committing a file)

Tags: svn, tree, commit, conflict, resolve

I am trying to update my changes to some python work onto an SVN server.  When I attempt to commit the file to the svn, I get an error that my folder is out of date:

"Transmitting file data .............svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Directory '/scripts/setup/configure' is out of date"

When I attempt to run "svn update configure/", it fails due to a Tree conflict:

"Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1"

I then attempt to resolve using "svn resolve --accept working -R .", which returns the output:

"Resolved conflicted state of 'configure'"

(Note, running the resolve command a second time in a row returns no output, as it is already 'resolved').

I then attempt to update, and get the same Tree conflict error as before.  I am now back at step one.  Attempting to resolve again will give the same output claiming that the issue has been resolved, but attempted to update 'un-resolves' the issue.

Any help/insight on this?  I've been working at it for quite some time and have gotten nowhere.

Thank you

Comment: If at all possible, delete the affected folder and `svn update`, or do a completely new checkout. SVN is like that sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kludgy though it may be, in the situations when I really can't work out why Subversion is spitting its dummy I just do a fresh checkout and then move my changes over by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Pike65's solution will work.  You can also do it on a smaller scale and just delete the conflicted files, do an update, and then re-apply your changes.